# Can't search for arabic characters in Sybase ASE 16 univarchar field type

Tags: sql, sybase, sql-like, arabic, ase

I have a table with two fields id and name.
Name field store arabic names like مينا and محمد
when i write:

```
select * from tablename where name like '%مينا%'
```

there is no output but i can see the table with arabic characters when write:

```
select * from tablename
```

could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: try:
`select * from tablename where name like '%مينا%'  collate 1256ARA`

Comment: got error: Incorrect syntax near 'collate'

Comment: 'collate' is not a supported construct in Sybase ASE.
Perhaps the issue is the client-server character set conversion? Did you try the -J utf8 option? (if you're using 'isql')

Comment: Thank you RobV yes its about client charset.

Comment: RobV your comment is an answer to me.